# Where's IHubFilter?

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, signalr

According to [this doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/hub-filters?view=aspnetcore-5.0), we should have Filter support in SignalR starting from .NET Core 5.0. Problem is that [IHubFilter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.signalr.ihubfilter?view=aspnetcore-5.0) interface is not included in any NuGet package. I need this feature to implement global exception handler in my project. Do you know what's wrong with SignalR Filters? Was this feature revoked or am I looking in wrong direction?

Thanks

Comment: Assembly and Namespace can be found here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.signalr.ihubfilter?view=aspnetcore-5.0

Comment: yep, problem is that its not there

Comment: I just created a new asp.net web application without any changes from the templates, and `IHubFilter` was available without adding any packages, or references. I think we are going to need more information on your setup to help you further.

Comment: ok that's weird. I initially created my app based on .net core 3.1 and upgraded to 5.0... let me replicate your steps...

Comment: Yep its working. But how do I get this into class library project? :/ That does not make sense, I can reference IHubFilter and SignalR based classes only from WebApi based templates...

Comment: See my new answer for information on using it in a library.

Comment: You need to target framework .NET 5.0 in your project properties

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a brand new ASP.NET Core Web Application using net5 and didn't make any changes. `IHubFilter` was available directly, without having to add any packages or assembly references.

When trying to use it in a library project, I had to add a reference to `Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Core.dll`, which happened to be located at `C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App\5.0.8\` on my computer. `IHubFilter` was then present in the namespace `Microsoft.ASpNetCore.SignalR`.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There is no nuget package, SignalR is included in the shared framework so you will automatically have a reference to it if you build a web app in 5.0+.

Comment: Can you share namespace please? I'm still unable to find it

Comment: Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR